# Cookieの値がブラウザ側で有効になるタイミングはいつか

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, cookie

「[ファイルダウンロード完了後に画面遷移などをjavascriptで行う](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/nabehiro/20140208/1391850498)」を参考にASP.NET MVCで実装してみました。

サーバー側はファイルをダウンロードをさせつつCookieをセット、クライアント側はJavaScriptで定期的にCookieをチェックすることでダウンロードの完了を検出する、というものですが、サーバーで設定した**Cookieがブラウザ側で有効になるのはサーバーからレスポンスデータをすべて受け取った後**と理解して良いでしょうか？

下記コードで実行してみましたが、レスポンスをすべて受信する前にCookieが有効になっているように思われました。（思われました、というのはダウンロードを途中で一時停止する方法が分からなかったので、ダウンロード完了前にalertが表示されてしまうことを確実に確認できていないため）

cshtmlは

```
<a href="/Home/Download" id="download">download</a>
<script>
  $('#download').click(function () {
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
      if ($.cookie('downloaded')) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        $.removeCookie('downloaded', { path: '/' });
        alert('ダウンロード完了');
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
</script>
```

コントローラーは

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    var cookie = new HttpCookie("downloaded");
    cookie.Value = "yes";
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    var path = @"c:\hoge.jpg";
    return File(path, "image/jpeg", "fuga.jpg");
}
```

Comment: 本当にやりたいことは、ダウンロード終了の検出ではないのですか？cookieで代用しようとするといろいろコーナーケースではまりそうですが。

Comment: 本当にやりたいことはダウンロード終了の検出です。ただし、その前提知識として、Cookieの仕様はどうなっているのか、このような同期を目的とした用途に使えるものかどうかを確認したくて、このような質問にさせて頂きました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

細かく実証したわけではないので、大幅に外している可能性はありますが、 Cookie の処理についての指示が書かれている、

- [RFC　6265 - HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) ([日本語訳](http://www.hcn.zaq.ne.jp/___/WEB/RFC6265-ja.html))

によると、「 **ブラウザがHTTP ヘッダをパースした時点で Cookie は設定される。** 」 と解釈できます。

> [*Section 5.2*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2)
> ...
> **When the user agent finishes parsing the set-cookie-string, the user agent is said to "receive a cookie" from the request-uri** with name cookie-name, value cookie-value, and attributes cookie-attribute-list.  (See Section 5.3 for additional requirements triggered by receiving a cookie.)

意訳「ブラウザが Set-Cookieヘッダ(set-cookie-string)をパースした時、『Cookie を受信せよ』とされたものとする。Cookie を受信する際の細かな要求事項については、 Section 5.3 を参照のこと」

とあるので、 Section 5.3 を読んでみますと、

> [*Section 5.3*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3)
> ...
> When the user agent "receives a cookie" from a request-uri with name cookie-name, value cookie-value, and attributes cookie-attribute-list, the user agent **MUST** process the cookie as follows:
>
> 1 .   A user agent MAY ignore a received cookie in its entirety.  For example, the user agent might wish to block receiving cookies from "third-party" responses or the user agent might not wish to store cookies that exceed some size.
> ...
> ...
> ...
> 12 .  Insert the newly created cookie into the cookie store.

項目(12) で Cookie ストレージに保管することが指定されています。

#### ■ Firefox の Cookie 確認ダイアログについて

Mozilla Firefox で `about:config` から `network.cookie.lifetimePolicy=1` とすることで、懐かしの Cookie 確認ダイアログが *－サイトによっては数百回も－* 表示されるようにできます。

そのダイアログの動作をみると、 `Set-Cookie` があるページを読込途中で確認ダイアログがポップアップし、ユーザが確認しなければページの読込が再開されません。これは、「HTTPヘッダのパース時、 Cookie の設定直前に処理を止め、その時点時点でクッキーを有効にするか確認している」と受け取ることができそうです。

Comment: 日本語訳にも「構文解析を終えたとき、クッキーを受信したとされる」という記述がありますね。`Firefox の Cookie 確認ダイアログ`で思い出したのですが、IEにも`Cookie 確認ダイアログ`を表示するオプションがあり（[インターネットオプション] - [プライバシー] - [詳細設定])、それで動作を確認したところ、Cookieの確認ダイアログで確認しないと、ファイル保存のダイアログが表示されませんので、やはりクッキーのほうが先のようですね。レスポンスデータの受信完了確認には、クッキーは使えなさそうです。ありがとうございます。